# ETS from fable package in R (can I do it with out tsibble)

Tags: r, time-series, fable-r

I am trying to use `ETS` function from `fable` package (following this tutorial [link](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/fable/)). Ideally I would like to do it without using `tsibble` functionality. In particular I am trying to generate forecast:

```
library(tsibble)
library(fable)
library(tidyverse)

fit <- ETS(1:63)

forecast(fit, h =2)
```

returns error:

```
Error in UseMethod("forecast") : 
  no applicable method for 'forecast' applied to an object of class "c('mdl_defn', 'R6')"
```

another try

```
summary(fit)
```

also returns error

```
Error in object[[i]] : wrong arguments for subsetting an environment
```

So can I used it without full `tsibble` functionality? It was so simple with ARIMA from forecast package. 
If it is not possible without `tsibble` what would be the quickest way to cast it as `tsibble` data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `tsibbles`, but it is very easy to do so.

```r
library(tsibble)
library(fable)
library(tidyverse)

ts(1:63) %>%
  as_tsibble() %>%
  model(ETS(value)) %>%
  forecast(h=2)

#> # A fable: 2 x 4 [1]
#> # Key:     .model [1]
#>   .model     index value .distribution
#>   <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dist>       
#> 1 ETS(value)    64    64 N(64, 0)     
#> 2 ETS(value)    65    65 N(65, 0)
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>